# how to make XHTML?

Tags: xslt, xhtml

i have code *xsl :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xhtml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:variable name="with" select="'File2.xml'" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h1>WEB Service</h1><br/>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">

<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
</xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
  <xsl:variable name="info" select="document($with)/Xml/data[ClassId=current()/ClassId]/." />
  <xsl:for-each select="$info/*">
    <xsl:if test="name()!='ClassId'">
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:transform>
```

im trying make XHTML, when i running just showing html not include xml fragment..

anyone can help me please ?

thanks

Comment: Pleas post an example of the XML input and the expected output of the transformation.

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 1):

> when i running just showing html not include xml fragment..

The reason for this is that the XSLT processor starts by applying the template matching the `/` root node. This template contains no `xsl:apply-templates` instructions, so the processing ends here.